# Cannot call static method in static class from other classes

Tags: c#, class, methods, static

I have a static class (C#):

```
public static class PRRoles
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return DAPRRoles.GetPRRoles();
            //Dictionary<int, string> returnme = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            //returnme = DAPRRoles.GetPRRoles();

            //return returnme;
        }
    }
    public static bool IsPRRole(RoleType RT)
    {
        return Roles.ContainsKey((int)RT);
    }

}
```

and this is how I call:

```
if(PRRoles.IsPRRole(RoleType.Contracts))
```

Here is class DAPRRoles with the method defined:

```
public class DAPRRoles
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> GetPRRoles()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dicRoles = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        try
        {
            DataTable PRRoles = new WFDataLayer().GetPRRoles();
            foreach (DataRow r in PRRoles.Rows)
            {
                dicRoles.Add(int.Parse(r["roleid"].ToString()), r["description"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog(String.Format("GetPRRoles() threw Exception"));
            WriteLog(String.Format("Message: {0}", ex.Message));
            throw new Exception("JacobsWF.DAPRRoles.GetPRRoles Exception : " + ex.ToString());
        }

        return dicRoles;

    }
}
```

note that I must type the method name because intellisense does not show it.

This is the enum definition for RoleType above and it is defined outside of any class and is used successfully throughout the code.

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    //Employee Types
    Employee = 1,
    JobManager = 2,
    Delegate = 3,
    JobManager2 = 4,
    //Purchase Request Buyer Types
    Buyer = 100, 
    BusinessAdmin = 101,
    Contracts = 102,
    Admin = 103,
    //Purchase Request Workflow Types
    [Description("Property Manager")]
    PropertyAdmin = 104,
    [Description("Contract Administrator")]
    ContractAdmin = 105,
    [Description("Office Director")]
    OfficeDirector = 106,
    [Description("Program Manager")]
    ProgramManager = 107,
    [Description("Financial Analyst")]
    FinancialAnalyst = 108,
    //Groups
    ADGroup = 1000,
    SharePointGroup = 2000,
    // External
    ExternalContact = 10000

}
```

IsPRRole is not visible to any other class, pages or methods and the application will not build if there are any calls to the method. Is this because the Roles Property of the class accesses data outside the code?

Is there an easy way to resolve this? Can I create a static method in the static class that would be visible?

One more note: There are multiple instances of calling static methods throughout the rest of the solution - which includes multiple projects - all compile and run successfully. This is the only one that is giving me this issue.

Thanks,
John

Comment: `IsPRRole is not visible to any other class, pages or methods` <= Yes it is. Both the method as well as the type are `public` which means that other types can access this method. Changes are you are just not calling it correctly like using an instance qualifier instead of the type qualifier or you are calling it from an outside namespace and did not namespace qualify the type. Your calling code would have this: `var result = PRRoles.IsPRRole(roleTypeParam);` with a possible namespace qualifier.

Comment: What is the compilation error when there are calls to the `IsPRRole` method and it does not build?

Comment: What type is `DAPRRoles`?  Is `GetPRRoles()` static?

Comment: Is the enum RoleType also public?

Comment: Why the down votes? No one who has responded has had a valid answer to my question. Therefore, it appears to be a valid legitimate question.

Comment: could you provide some sample code of how your trying to call it?  From all appearances this should work fine for you. Based on the information you've provided, you shouldn't be running into the problem you're stating unless you are doing something else wrong. RoleType and DAPRoles are a mystery to us.  What are they? and where/how are they defined.

Comment: @Igor No it is not. As you can see from the code above, there is a public property in the class. That property IS visible anyplace I want to use it. The method from that class is NOT.

Comment: @steve16351 the error message is:Error 264 'PurchaseRequest.PRRoles' does not contain a definition for 'IsPRRole'

Comment: @JohnWu  DAPRroles is standard (not static) public class. GetPRRoles is static.

Comment: @gdir: yes the enum is public.

Comment: In your question you need to include the error message as well as the line it appears on.

Comment: What is `PurchaseRequest`? Is `PRRoles` nested within that class, or is that a namespace?

Comment: You say the error is Error 264 'PurchaseRequest.PRRoles' does not contain a definition for 'IsPRRole'.  No, PurchaseRequest (whatever that is) probably doesn't have a definition for IsPRRole.  The class `PRRoles` has that definition.  You need to call it as `PRRoles.IsPRRole(someInt);`

Answer (score 1):

You call static methods using the class name.  So, if I boil your code down to something that compiles.  I've updated my repro so that it's closer to your code (by including a DAPRRoles class and a RoleType enum).  You should be able to create a simple console or WinForms or WPF app, throw this code in, see it compile and step through it by calling `PRRoles.IsPRRole(someInt);` :

```
public static class PRRoles {
    public static Dictionary<int, string> Roles {
        get {
            return DAPRRoles.GetPRRoles();
        }
    }
    public static bool IsPRRole(int i){
        return Roles.ContainsKey(i);
    }
}

public class DAPRRoles {
    public static Dictionary<int, string> GetPRRoles() {
        Dictionary<int, string> dicRoles = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dicRoles.Add(1, "One");
        dicRoles.Add(5, "five");
        return dicRoles;
    }
}

public enum RoleType {
    Undefined = 0,
    Employee = 1,
    JobManager = 2,
    Delegate = 3,
    JobManager2 = 4,
}
```

I can call it (from somewhere else in my app) this way: `PRRoles.IsPRRole(1);` and see true returned, if I pass 2, I see false.

Comment: The code compiles perfectly with the static method in the class as long as I do not try to call ti from someplace else. The public static property Roles works perfectly.

Comment: @John: Did you just down-vote because you believe that my code (above), that I put together (since your code included references to types whose source you did not post) and compiled into a test program does not compile?  My code doesn't run (it will throw a null reference exception), but I assure you that it compiles, both the class and the call.  After changing my "return null" statement to return a new Dictionary (still bad code, but the exception is gone), I can call and step through the code and see it return false.  My code compiles!  If it doesn't for you, you aren't copying it properly.

Comment: I down voted because you essentially have what I have which does not contribute to the resolution. Your solution is not really any different from mine. I probably should have shown more code in the original post but every piece of that additional code runs flawlessly w/o modifications. The dictionary is populated successfully when called in the rest of the code and the enum definitions work perfectly as well.Also, if I use   if (PRRoles.Roles.ContainsKey((int)app.role)) that works. So, that tells me the method that populates Roles also works perfectly.

Comment: What's different from your code, by the way, is that my code is a full, self-contained repro.  Anyone should be able to copy my code, drop in an app, put a breakpoint in (on the call the `PRRoles.IsPRRole(someInt);`) and step through it.  Your code was not self-contained.